# Django password validators

Tags: django, change-password

Django 1.11.8

How could I change the password restrictions?
I edited setting.py with this example:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.form.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'min_length': 4,
    }
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
```

]

But the warning message doesn't change (always 8 chars for example). Is it enough to change the length options?
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have saved the changes to settings and restarted the server before reloading the password change page.

Comment: @Alasdair done everything! But I read always 8 characters

Comment: Note you have `'django.contrib.auth.form.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'` instead of `'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'` as shown in the docs. I don't think that's the issue though.

Comment: I have to modify the minimumlenth and disable the others validations, possibily only for the user (even if it's not important)

Answer (score 0):

It should be changed. If you check the source code for `MinimumLengthValidator`.

```
class MinimumLengthValidator(object):
    """
    Validate whether the password is of a minimum length.
    """
    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if len(password) < self.min_length:
            raise ValidationError(
                ungettext(
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
                    "This password is too short. It must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
                    self.min_length
                ),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'min_length': self.min_length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return ungettext(
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d character.",
            "Your password must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.",
            self.min_length
        ) % {'min_length': self.min_length}
```

Maybe reload server (or restart runserver)

If it doesn't change, you have option to make your own validator. 
check docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator)